# PySIde6 QWidget Inheritence problem.Shows a gap between the widget 4 and 5 beliving the Class I inherited called self does not show up

Tags: pyside6

PySIde6 QWidget Inheritence problem.Shows a gap between the widget 4 and 5 beliving the Class I inherited called self does not show up.If anyone can help me I appreciate.When I call the class I set parent to None.

```py
from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QLocale,
    QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QRect,
    QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor,
    QFont, QFontDatabase, QGradient, QIcon,
    QImage, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPainter,
    QPalette, QPixmap, QRadialGradient, QTransform)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QLineEdit,
    QPushButton, QScrollArea, QSizePolicy, QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget)
import myimages_rc
from controlgui import ControlSystemGUI

class BWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,Username,Password,Website,parent):
        
        QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        
        self.Username = Username
        self.Password = Password
       
        
        
        
        #The backend code
        
        self.deletebutton.clicked.connect(self.deleteit)
        self.UsernameButton.hide()
        self.PasswordEdit.hide()
        self.WebsiteEdit.hide()
        
    def deleteit(self):
        print("Hello")
        
        
    def HidePassword(self,password):     
        word = ""   
        for i in range(len(password)):
            word = word+"*"    
        
        return word
```

I tried to make a widget and It did not show up.This is a minimalist version.Ofc I declared the stuff from tehre

Comment: What are "widget 4 and 5"? Where or how are they created? How do you think we would be able to help you if the only code you provide shows absolutely **nothing** of what you're asking? Please [edit] your post to provide a valid [mre], and ensure that the code is properly *readable* in the post preview before submitting.